# How to write click function for icon using cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have 3 icons
[image: icon image]

and html part is

Need these 3 icon click ?How to do this, its have same class name, same id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `src` attribute for this. I could see in the html image that there are two diff type of icons - `GlobalCOnfig` and `Customer`. SO you can do something like:

```js
cy.get('[src*="/static/media/GlobalConfig"]').click()
cy.get('[src*="/static/media/Customer"]').click()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to address the first one of these use `.eq(0)`, for the 2nd `.eq(1)`and so on.

```js
cy.get('#panelid-header).eq(0).click()
```

If you want to click all of them in succession

```js
cy.get('#panelid-header).each(($el) => {
   cy.get($el).click()
   })
```